# how to strip out white spaces from html document

Tags: regex

I am trying to find a valid regular expression that i can use to strip out all the white spaces or new line characters.

Below is something I tried.

**((\s|\n|\r)*?<(\s|\n|\r)*?)|(\s|\n|\r)*?>(\s|\n|\r)***

on this document

```
< tag src="abc" testattribute >


<script > any script </script >

<tag2>what is this </tag2>
<tag>
```

I want the end result to be exactly this.

```
<tag src="abc" testattribute><script>any script</script><tag2>what is this</tag2><tag>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `\s` here to match for whitespace.

```
\s matches whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
```

Depending on the language you are using, you can use assertions for this.

```
(?<=<|>)\s*|(?<!>|<)\s*(?![^><])
```

See [`live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/sK5hD7)

Regular expression:

```
(?<=           look behind to see if there is:
 <             '<'
  |             OR
 >             '>'
)              end of look-behind
 \s*           whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 |             OR
(?<!           look behind to see if there is not:
 >             '>'
  |            OR
 <             '<'
)              end of look-behind
 \s*           whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
 (?!           look ahead to see if there is not:
  [^><]        any character except: '>', '<'
 )             end of look-ahead
```

Comment: I was looking for a javascript solution for others here is what i tried with hwnd's solution.

(?=<|>)\s*|(?!>|<)\s*(?![^><])

Comment: Maybe try: `(?:<|>)(\s*)|(?!>|<)\s*(?![^><])`